# Does increasing of a field size require disabling and enabling cdc for a table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, change-data-capture

I have to increase the size of a table field from 255 to 4000 chars. CDC is enabled for that table. Before I alter the column, should I disable cdc for the table or is the change picked-up automatically?

I read this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937(v=sql.105).aspx, however, it is not clear from the Handling Changes to Source Tables what happens when the field size changes. Are the CT tables altered automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I tested this and the field size change is picked-up automatically!